# React & Node (Multer): Image is not found by path while it exists on that path

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

hello i have image uploading feature on my website, and it is uploaded in special folder with NodeJS (Express) and [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) but problem is  that when user uploads that image he is redirected to freshly created route and on that route the image is supposed to display, but it does not even thought it exists
here is multer code:

```
const imgStorageBaseURL = '/images'
const imgStoragePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'images');
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    const userPath = path.join(imgStoragePath, req.userId);
    fs.mkdir(
      userPath,
      () => callback(null, userPath)
    )
  },


  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    const filenameParts = file.originalname.split('.');
    const ext = filenameParts.pop();
    const basename = filenameParts.join('.');
    const additionalPath = Date.now() + '' +  Math.floor(Math.random() * (2000 - 500)) + 500;
    callback(null, basename + '-' + additionalPath + '.' + ext);
  }
})
```

and here is array of that image links (to save that links into db)

```
 var imgarray = []
 req.files.forEach((file) => {
    imgarray.push(imgStorageBaseURL + '/' + req.userId + '/' + file.filename)
    console.log(imgarray)
})
```

and react code

```
     {this.state.imageURLs.map((src, k)=>{
         return (
             <img src={src} key={k} alt="Hey" className="img"/>
         )
     })}
```

there is source in inspect element

[image]

and here is proof that image exists on that path

[image]

but when i visit that url in source i got this

[image]

what is the reason that causes this misunderstanding?

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the image exists in the filesystem fine, it is not correctly placed **"relative"** to the web server i.e your React Application.

Usually images are placed in separate areas designated for static files.If you had used `create-react-app` to build your app, they can be accessed from the `'public'` folder

```
render() {
  // Note: this is an escape hatch and should be used sparingly!
  // Normally we recommend using `import` for getting asset URLs
  // as described in “Adding Images and Fonts” above this section.
  return <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/logo.png'} />;
}
```

Here is the [link to the official docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-the-public-folder).

Specifically you should update your react code to:

```
 {this.state.imageURLs.map((src, k)=>{
     return (
         <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL +src} key={k} alt="Hey" className="img"/>
     )
 })}
```

Just make sure to move the images or update the path where images get saved from multer/express to the public folder.

Comment: i have separate folder called images

Comment: is it inside your public folder?

Comment: Yes, react application looks for /images inside your public folder as it is a static asset. You will also need to "process.env.PUBLIC_URL" add before ur src. First try with image there. Then you can update your server code to upload images into that path

Comment: what if i add this line `app.use('/images', express.static('./images'))` in server file?

Comment: If you need to work that way, then you need to append `"http://localhost:8000/"` to your src inside image tag. So every time it will be fetched from the server (8000  or whatever your server port is)

Comment: so i have to move 'images' folder into public folder right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194711/discussion-between-arjithn-and-ilia).